# Getting oldest DateTime in a List?

Tags: java, list, sorting, methods, collections

I have a list of Dog `Entities` that contain the field `"Birthday".`

I would like to have a method in the entity class that returns only the oldest `DateTime` in the list.

How can I do so?

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOG")
public class Dog
{

//some other fields

@Column(name = "BIRTHDAY")
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
    private DateTime birthday;
```

**Example of List:**

```
private List<Dog> dogList;
```

Comment: implement comparable interface. Override compareTo method. Override equals and hashcode. reverse sort list and get the top most element.

Comment: Please give an example of this

Comment: @sidgate that is a c# answer, this is java

Comment: @java123999 - I have already given enough clues. Can't do your homework now :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 using a stream and a lambda to create the comparator, then get the birthday from the `Optional`:

```
public static DateTime getOldestDogsBirthday(final Collection<? extends Dog> dogs) {
    return dogs.stream().min((d1, d2) -> d1.getBirthday().compareTo(d2.getBirthday())).get().getBirthday();
}
```

**Update:** Even more concise example based on suggestion in comments to use `getBirthday` as a method reference passed into `Comparator.comparing`:

```
return dogs.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Dog::getBirthday)).get().getBirthday();
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I return the oldest DateTime in a method?

Comment: I don't understand why there are 3 .getBirthday methods?

Comment: @java123999 - I've updated to wrap it in a method.  The first two calls to `getBirthday` are within the comparator, to do the actual sorting. The final one is to get the birthday from the `Optional`

Comment: Maybe you can map first, and then there's less birthdays :)

Comment: the comparator can be written more concisely with `stream().min(comparing(Dog::getBirthday))` (and a static import of `Comparator.comparing`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what is the method actually returning then? The DateTime of the oldest Quote Option in the list?

Comment: @java123999 - the method returns the birthday (Date) of the oldest dog in the given collection

Comment: @java123999 - thanks for accepting the answer, glad it was useful. Just updated to use Joda DateTime btw - works exactly the same

Comment: Thanks it was very helpful, I am having a related issue with comparators here if you would like to look at it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767715/adding-a-second-clause-to-compareto-method-to-stop-duplicates-being-removed

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example without lambada expressions:

```
public DateTime findOldestDogsBirthday() {
    Collections.sort(dogList, new Comparator<Dog>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Dog o1, Dog o2) {
            DateTime d1 = o1.getBirthday();
            DateTime d2 = o2.getBirthday();
            return d1.compareTo(d2);
        }
    });
    return !dogList.isEmpty() ? dogList.get(0).getBirthday() : null;
}
```